# Multithreading in ResultSet

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm developing a program that retrieves the cursor from a stored procedure in Oracle and writes the result in a text file. The cursor is expected to return a total of 2M records and over 400+ columns and the result is stored a **ResultSet**

Before the program writes to the text file, It will check the columns for masking and if the column is tagged to be masked it will masked the field using Salt and Key Encryption.

The program is working as expected however the runtime is longer that expected. Last runtime was 10 hours but only wrote 20k records out of the 2M.

Is there a way to use multithreading where the program will handle multiple records instead on just one by one.

I tried this setup before but it's not threading as expected:

```
ExecutorService threadPool =Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

       while(rs.next()){ 
               //rs is a ResultSet
        threadPool.execute(new Runnable(){
        @Override
         public void run(){
               //the program that will setup the record and check if a field needs to be masked is placed here.
             }
           });
        }
    threadPool.shutdown();
```

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: How are you processing rows from `ResultSet`? `ResultSet` and writing into a file is inherently sequential so you can't parallelize that. Plus the network or disk overhead may dominate your runtime anyways. 20k in 10 hours sounds like a hang. Column encryption might be parallelizable but doubtful how much that helps with time.

Comment: Instead of throwing threads at it as a solution, figure out what takes so long. For instance start by changing the JDBC fetch size (default is 10 which means a lot of roundtrips to the db, change to for instance 100 or 1000 to reduce network traffic). Having multiple threads write to a file is going to give you more trouble then you solve.

Comment: Definitely you can't do a result set over a huge amount of data returned from the db.

Comment: Yes, but you need to copy the current row in memory before you submit it to the thread pool.

Comment: @RomanC May I ask on a better on this one? I've only used ResultSet in retrieve from the DB.

Comment: @slowjava If you used RrsultSet then you must close it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check where is the bottleneck of your application. I suppose that is not something that you can solve with multithreading.

To identify the bottleneck work step by step:

- try to execute manually the query locally to the database to see the performances of the query. Use it to check if there are indexes to add or any other optimization at query level
- try to extract records from the database without do nothing with them to check to speed connection between the database and the java application. Use it to identify if the problem is the connectivity between the server hosting the database and the server hosting the java application. Check if you can reduce the size of the single record (for example don't extract all the fields with a select * if you don't need them, but select field by field)
- check the speed to write the file. Use buffered streams to increase speed. Don't hold the whole file in memory but stream it periodically to disk
- If you perform any long operation for each record retrieved from the database try to spend your time on that code. Eventually in this case you can use the multithreading